# Switch between two .reg files

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I'm looking for a quick and easy way (I don't need any error checking) to switch between two reg files by opening a batch file.

If a user runs a batch file, the batch file should merge reg file A to the registry. If the user runs it again, the batch file should merge reg file B to the registry. If the user runs it again, file A is merged... you get the point.

In general, I think there are two ways to do this:

1. Create some sort of variable to store which reg should be run next.
2. Check the registry key values to see which reg has been merged most recently (probably the preferred method).

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
REG QUERY "KeyName" /v "ValueName" | Find "x"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 regedit /S file1.reg
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 regedit /S file2.reg
```

The REG QUERY part seems to work, but at the `IF ERRORLEVEL` statements something is going wrong. But maybe I should use a different method altogether.

Hoping for some suggestions.. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Sorry for being a bit vague: I believe the previous solution didn't work, because when the first `IF` is correct, the second `IF` will be too after the first `IF`'s command. So I will need an `IF ELSE` statement to prevent running the second `IF`.

I've now come up with this solution, which works:

```
REG QUERY "KeyName" /v "ValueName" | Find "x
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (REGEDIT /S "file1.reg") ELSE REGEDIT /S "file2.reg"
```

I was also wondering: would it be an improvement to have the registry key/values added inside the batch file instead of using seperate .reg files? The value types are REG_BINARY and REG_DWORD.

Comment: What does "something is going wrong" mean? We're not sitting at your keyboard and can't see your screen from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
REG QUERY "KeyName" /v "ValueName" | Find "x"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  regedit /S file1.reg
  goto :EOF
)
regedit /S file2.reg
```

The IF condition is set to TRUE when the ERRORLEVEL is equal to, or greater than, the ERRORLEVEL number (see here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/39585/en-us) so the second IF condition is always evaluated as true.

Comment: Thanks! I think I prefer that over my current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a value in a enviroment variable

```
@Echo OFF
:: By Elektro H@cker
Set | FIND "Merged" >NUL && Regedit /S "File_B.reg" || Regedit /S "File_A.reg" && SETX Merged YES >NUL
Pause&Exit
```

This is the same code but indented and with a quickly explanation:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

REM If it's batfile first launch then I add a value "YES" to a variable and then only merges the File A.
REM If isn't batfile first launch then only merges FILE B

Set | FIND "Merged" >NUL && (
     Regedit /S "File_B.reg"
) || Regedit /S "File_A.reg" && (
     SETX Merged YES >NUL
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just so you know: I accepted the other answer because I found it a little bit more intuitive.